# Get values from XML field with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the value from a xml column with T-SQL.

My xml column named `XML` contains :

```
<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="4" ONPASS="0"/>
```

How can I get the second parameter? For example here ID.

I have tried a request like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SELECT @xml = N'<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="4" ONPASS="0"/>'

SELECT
    T.C.value('(SIMBATCHJOB)[1]', 'int') as test1
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('SIMBATCHJOB') T(C)
```

My table is structured like this:

```
ID | XML
```

If I try this query:

```
Select ID
      ,Value = cast([xml] as xml).value('SIMBATCHJOB[1]/@ID','int')
From  SIM_JOBS
where id = 179
```

This query return me the ID and the Value is empty

Do you understand this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Attributes are not ordered. You can get the value of `ID` (with `SIMBATCHJOB/@ID`), but literally wanting to have the value of "the second parameter" is going to fail if the element is `<SIMBATCHJOB ID="4" ONFAIL="2" ONPASS="0"/>`, which, as far as XML is concerned, is exactly the same thing. So do you know the attribute you want, or do you really have some weird arrangement where you always need the second attribute but the name of that could vary?

Comment: Agree with Jeroen. But if you still want to access the first attribute you can use the xpath `SIMBATCHJOB/@*[1]`

Comment: The name ID don't change and it's always on the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeroen is 100% correct, but one option is to use a CROSS APPLY and normalize your attributes.

The Sequence will hold true to the sequence in the actual XML.  I suspect you could filter as needed.

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml = '<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="4" ONPASS="0"/>'

Select Seq       = row_number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
      ,Attribute = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value     = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/SIMBATCHJOB ')  as C1(n)
 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
```

**Returns**

```
Seq Attribute Value
1   ONFAIL    2
2   ID        4
3   ONPASS    0
```

> **EDIT - Update for Comments  ---**

This will return the SECOND Attribute/Value **regardles** of what is is

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[xml] xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="4"  ONPASS="0"/>'),
(2,'<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="99" ONPASS="1"/>')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (
                Select *
                 From (
                        Select Seq       = row_number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
                              ,Attribute = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                              ,Value     = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                         From  A.xml.nodes('/SIMBATCHJOB ')  as C1(n)
                         Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                      ) B1
                 Where B1.Seq=2
            ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Seq Attribute   Value
1   2   ID          4
2   2   ID          99
```

> **EDIT 2:  -  Get JUST ID regardless of Sequence**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[xml] xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="4"  ONPASS="0"/>'),
(2,'<SIMBATCHJOB ONFAIL="2" ID="99" ONPASS="1"/>')

Select A.ID
      ,Value = [xml].value('SIMBATCHJOB[1]/@ID','int')
From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value
1   4
2   99
```

Comment: I need the result return me just "4" can you explain me how to do that ?

Comment: @dutycorpse Just to be clear.  You are looking for the SECOND attribute/value or the  value from the attribute ID ?

Comment: @dutycorpse Also, do you want this to be from a table and not a variable?

Comment: Yes from a table my column is named XML and I want just the value on the second parameter. So in my example the value on the second parameter is "4" so when I launch my query I would like to get me just "4".

Comment: @dutycorpse See Update/Edit

Comment: For completeness, you may want to mention what's needed when you always fetch `ID`, as it's much simpler, and much more likely to be applicable in general.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are 100% correct ... again.  Still not 100% if OP wants 2nd attribute or a specific ID.   I will make the edit.

Comment: Also, although I've never seen it actually fail, and I think XML queries will actually not parallelize, the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` trick is still not guaranteed to assign numbers in result set order. If you have to use it, you have to use it, but you should feel appropriately apprehensive when putting this in production. Normally this could be fixed by establishing the node order within XML (you can count nodes in order in an XML query), but I'm not sure that works for attributes. I'm not highly motivated to write a FLWOR for it, though. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've never seen i fail on table variables, and/or XML.  Certainly no gtd with a table.  FLWOR makes my brain bleed.  I'm not that smart.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Just to be clear, I'm very confident that (Order By (Select NULL)) maintains the sequence with table variables and XML.  For example, I've inherited a horrible GL extract which has been running for years.  If the sequence ever failed, the GL would be out-of-balance and all sorts of bells and alarms would go off.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti can you look my update in my post. Thanks

Comment: @dutycorpse xml is a reserved word  use   [xml].value...  Notice the []'s

Comment: I have the same error when I use [xml] how can I target my column XML ?

Comment: @dutycorpse Is the datatype of column [XML] a varchar or xml ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: I've developed a very healthy aversion to "I have never seen this fail in all my years" experiences for SQL Server, after having actually having seen some things fail after all those years, and then concluding that yes, technically the engine was permitted to screw me over. :-) I will immediately admit that this particular case is, fortunately, not one of them. I merely pointed it out to emphasize that, where possible, alternatives should be considered first, even if they, say, hurt performance.

Comment: the datatype on my database is varchar but xml is stocked on it and the name on this colum is XML

Comment: @dutycorpse   then you have to convert to XML   for example ...     ,Value = cast([xml] as xml).value('SIMBATCHJOB[1]/@ID','int')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti when I use the cast the query work but return me just the ID and the value is empty

Comment: @dutycorpse couple of times.  1) xml is case sensitive.  2) are you sure there is valid XML  where id = '179'  .... also is 179 an string or int?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I'm sur for my id the xml is valid, it's a integer sorry.

Comment: @dutycorpse then that makes me believe you have some invalid XML.  try Select ID,cast([XML] as xml) from your table where ID=179   If it returns null, than you have some bogus xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165573/discussion-between-dutycorpse-and-john-cappelletti).